# FTP command-line scripting in bat file doesn't work in Windows 8.1

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp, windows-8.1, command-prompt

The script below works perfectly in Windows 7 to script an FTP download:

```
echo user MyUSN> ftpcmd.dat
echo MyPWD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd FTP-Incoming/DB_Backups>> ftpcmd.dat
::echo get %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo get %1 C:\Database\Backups\%1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat www.fit-track.net
del ftpcmd.dat
```

But in Windows 8.1 it fails:

```
C:\windows\system32>ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat www.myserver.com
Connected to myserver.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
ftp> user MyUSN
331 Password required for MyUSN.

230 User logged in.
ftp> bin
200 Type set to I.
ftp> cd FTP-Incoming/DB_Backups
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> get  C:\Database\Backups\
200 PORT command successful.
550 The parameter is incorrect.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

This is a [well-documented approach](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/) shown on many websites.

Why does this fail in Windows 8.1 and how can I make it work?

Comment: This was PEBKAC and should be deleted. It adds no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously did not provide an argument when calling your batch file.

The `%1` resolved to an empty string.

Ultimately instead of correct

```
get file.txt C:\Database\Backups\file.txt
```

you call

```
get  C:\Database\Backups\
```

That's a wrong syntax, as the local path is used for a remote path.

The server rightfully rejects the command.